# Get id attribute from another element in same list item with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
    <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"></p>
    <span id="122"></span>
    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"></h3>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"></p>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"><a class="ui-link">Report</a></p>
</li>
```

So here is my HTML markup.

Goal: I need JQuery code that will give me the `id` value of the `<span>` element (so in this case: 122) within the same `<li>`, when I click the `<a>` in that same `<li>`.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have one span tag in your list items, you should be able to get your span's id with this:

```
$('a.ui-link').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).closest('li').find('span:first').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: doesn't find return an collection? haven't tested this may work fine.

Comment: It would ordinarily, but I'm filtering on the first element found so it will only return one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one span as in your html...

```
$('a.ui-link').live('click', function(){
   var id = $('span', $(this).closest('li')).attr('id');
});
```